# Error 1067: Invalid default value for created_at

Tags: mysql

Im trying to import my sql file backup to my new server, but i receive error:

Error 1067: Invalid default value for created_at

this is my SQL file header:

```
-- phpMyAdmin SQL Dump
-- version 4.8.3
-- https://www.phpmyadmin.net/
--
-- Host: localhost:3306
-- Generation Time: Nov 07, 2018 at 07:43 AM
-- Server version: 5.7.24
-- PHP Version: 7.2.7

SET SQL_MODE = "NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";
SET AUTOCOMMIT = 0;
START TRANSACTION;
SET time_zone = "+00:00";


/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8mb4 */;

--
-- Database: `.....
```

Error:

[image: error]

i added sql_mode line inside the conf file at:
/etc/mysql/my.cnf

[image: ddl]

restart mysql and apache2, but still not resolved

any idea please?

Comment: What is your MySQL version ? `Current_Timestamp` is not supported by older versions

Comment: Server version: 5.5.62-0ubuntu0.14.04.1 - (Ubuntu)

Comment: it will be better to go with mysql 8 and ubuntu 18?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Colums with the `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` attribute must have the data type `TIMESTAMP`, not `DATETIME`, in MySQL versions prior to 5.6.

So you need

```
`created_at` TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

or a later version of MySQL.

Comment: ubuntu 18 and mysql 8 will fix it without to edit the sql?

Comment: by the way, it fixed the problem thank you very much:) i edited the lines to TIMESTAMP and now its fine.

Comment: The operating system version doesn't matter. Any MySQL version 5.6.4 or better will deal with this problem, as will changing the column definition.